# "Cannot contact service to set scan periods" - during ble scan

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am scanning ble using background service and also from activity. so when background service and activity both running parallel then scanning is not given any beacon. so i am stopping service when scanning activity is open then it gives "Cannot contact service to set scan periods" error. after that scanning is stop in activity

Answer (score 0):

I had same setup first - a foreground Activity and a backgound Service, both communicating with BLE peripheral.

But then I have rewritten my Activity just to communicate with the Service - and only the latter communicates with BLE peripheral:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Intent mServiceIntent;
    private ScanService mService;
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
              ScanBinder sb = (ScanBinder) binder;
              mService = sb.getService();
              mService.setActivity(MainActivity.this);
              Utils.showToast(MainActivity.this, "Connected to service");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
              Utils.showToast(MainActivity.this, "Disconnected from service");
              mService.setActivity(null);
              mService = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ScanService.class);
        startService(mServiceIntent);
......

public class ScanService extends Service {
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mActivity != null)
            Utils.showToast(this, "Service (re)started");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

This kind of communication is described in [9. Exercise: Define and consume local service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#exercise_bindlocalservice) tutorial by Lars Vogel.